# Simultaneous post editing

Tags: support, editing

Recently I noticed that some posts are not editable:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

I thought there is a git-alike system under the hood, allowing simultaneous editing (probably it were the diffs in posts' history that made me think so), but it seems like this not the case. Does it also mean that there is a live queue of proposed edits, and the fewer edits (or fewer iterations of edit) were made the easier it is for the mods to sort things out efficiently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users with more than 2,000 rep are granted two important abilities regarding editing:

- edit without hassle: that is, their edits would take effect immediately, and
- review edit suggestions of users with less than 2,000 rep.

You'd notice a "review" button right beside your name on the top bar. Since you have more than 500 rep and less than 2,000, two of six review queues should be available to you.

Any user with more than 2,000 rep can review edits placed in the suggested edit queue, and it's not only mods, and on Chem, 2 reject or approve votes decide the fate of the edit suggestion.

I'd be leaving a bunch of fancy links but I'm on mobile.

Comment: Please don't worry about the links, I've got the idea. Thank you!

Comment: "Since you have more than 500 rep and less than 2,000..."  < *Flags as "obsolete"* > O:)

Answer (score 7):

There is no 'source-control' style of tracking of the edits.  If two people (both with edit privileges) start making separate edits based on one version of a post, the person who submits their edit first will have that edit completely overridden when the second person submits theirs, if the second person's edit is ["more substantial"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93247/278590) (thanks, Mart & ortho). It can be kind of annoying, actually.

The site moderators do not have any ongoing role with the edits/suggested edits process. They only get involved if they choose to, based on their own interactions with the site or on flags raised by other community members.

Comment: The first statement is only true if the second edit is *more* extensive than the first.

Comment: *[INSERT EXPOSTULATION]* Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Where are your fancy links? Huh huh? I assume you're not a mobile comp Chem function.

Comment: @M.A.R. Are you insulting my vaguely artificial intelligence??

Comment: It's a warning you should get when you edit a version that has just been edited. I guess there is documentation somewhere™... But maybe I'm just wrong.

Comment: I found the documentation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/. *Only* took me 15 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the thing about edit conflicts involving <2k rep users, which hasn't been addressed yet, this is what happens.

If Alice, a <2k user, suggests an edit on a post that has not yet been approved/rejected, then all other <2k rep users will not be able to suggest another edit. I can assume that this is in place to prevent edit conflicts.

On top of that, if Alice's suggested edit has not yet been approved/rejected, then all >2k rep users will be prompted to review the edit before editing further.

One exception is if Alice starts to edit a post, and before Alice submits her suggested edit, a >2k rep user (Bob) starts editing it as well. In that case, when Bob submits his edit, it will always override Alice's edit, and Alice's edit will be marked as rejected. Source: [Can we get a better conflict resolution to edits vs suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166861/312770)

I am not sure what happens if two <2k rep users edit a post simultaneously. Anybody willing to try?

---

Us mods don't care much for edits, unless there is a rollback war going on. Thankfully, those are few and far between. So, no need to worry about inconveniencing anybody. For the most part, suggested edits are handled very well by the community.